# В build скрипте используется shell команда rm, которой в windows нет- чем заменить?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, shell

Для сборки проекта есть такой скрипт

```js
{
  "name": "mern-client",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "Simple starter package for Redux with React and Babel support",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm ls react && webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js",
    "start": "serve ../docs",
    "build": "rm -rf ../docs && webpack --config webpack.prod.js && npm run copy:static",
    "copy:static": "cp -rf ./src/statics ../docs"
  },
```

В консоли: "rm" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Какие ещё варианты, кроме установки cygwin или запуска виртуализации?

Это не сработало "build": "rd /s /q ../docs && webpack --config webpack.prod.js && npm run copy:static",
    "copy:static": "cp -rf ./src/statics ../docs"

Недопустимый ключ: "docs".

ну и `"cp -rf"` тоже чем то надо заменять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## вариант 1

для `dev start build` создать по js файлу и выполнять **всё** средствами *nodejs*

например `rm -rf` [удаление директории рекурсивно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32197381/4794368)

## вариант 2

попробовать вот эту штуку (не проверял)

- https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs

в вашем случае, должно получиться что-то вроде этого:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm ls react && webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js",
        "start": "serve ../docs",
        "build": "shx rm -rf ../docs && webpack --config webpack.prod.js && npm run copy:static",
        "copy:static": "shx cp -rf ./src/statics ../docs"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "shelljs": "^0.8.3"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

добавить в devDependencies пакет `rimraf` и переписать скрипт таким образом:

```
"build": "rimraf ../docs && webpack..."
```

будет работать кросплатформено

Comment: а, еще просьба была по cp дать совет. так вот. создай приложение через create-react-app. там будут настроены все скрипты и они будут работать кросплатформенно